# As to improve the Selenium 2 test speed?

Tags: selenium2, java

I'm trying to create Selenium tests to my Java application, but each test spends about 5 seconds to execute. The most time consuming part of the test is to initialize the Selenium.

I'm initialize the web driver `@before` each test and kill the driver `@after` test.

Is there any way to start the webdriver and "restart it" every test?
Or should I start it and run all tests and then finishes him off?
How do I can reduce the time of tests?

I'm using selenium 2, maven and Junit 4.

So I am starting and finishing the tests

```
@Before
public  void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}

@After
public  void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: It might help for you to elaborate on what you mean by "initialize Selenium".  For example, do you start a new browser for every test?

Comment: yes, I start a new browser for every test.

Comment: how should be the structure for the tests? should have a webDriverPool that provides the driver?

I know a little Selenium, but I have problems with the structure of the tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people may prefer to use a new `Driver` instance for every test in order to avoid one test's side-effects from impacting another test.  I have never run into that problem.  For efficiency reasons, I try to re-use a single `Driver` for all tests in a suite.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with User246 and here is an example of how to do:

```
protected WebDriver getWebDriver() {

  if (driver == null) {
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  }
  return driver;
}
```